# Annotating swagger models (@ApiModelProperty) and apis/resources in different binaries/packages

Tags: java, swagger

Is annotating your data models in a different library/package and apis in a different package supported? Has any one tried this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any problem with that as long as everything is loaded within the scope of a single classloader. The scanning will be done on anything that's reachable.